# Adding and deleting items from grid view Android

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I have a grid view with some images. and an add button at the end of the grid view. I want to add new images to this grid from the phone gallery through the add button. And also I have to delete the item from the grid when I click on each image in the grid. I have tried a lots of tutorials but nothing can fit my requirements. Please help .
This is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView gv;
String [] web ={"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
int [] images={
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher
};
GridAdapter adapter ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
     adapter = new GridAdapter(MainActivity.this, web, images);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);

//code for add button..

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// this code is to open the phone gallery 
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                       android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);

            }

    });
}

//this is to get selected image from phone gallery
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case 1234:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
             Integer xx = Integer.valueOf(filePath);

            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

           }
    }

};


}
```

This is my grid Adapter class

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private Context mcontext;
  private final String [] web;
  private final int[] images;
  public GridAdapter (Context c , String [] web ,int [] images){
  mcontext = c;
  this.images = images;
  this.web = web;
  }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return web.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View grid;
LayoutInflater layoutinflatr = (LayoutInflater)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
if (convertView == null) {

    grid = new View(mcontext);
    grid = layoutinflatr.inflate(R.layout.gridxml, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tv.setText(web[position]);
    iv.setImageResource(images[position]);
}
else{
    grid = (View) convertView;
}
  grid.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // code to delete the selected item.
    }
});     



    return grid;
}


}
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ArrayList` instead of `Array`

Update your codel like below.

```
    String[] web = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
    int[] images = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher
    };

    ArrayList<Integer> NewImages;
    ArrayList<String> NewWeb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NewImages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        NewWeb = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < web.length; i++) {
            NewImages.add(images[i]);
            NewWeb.add(web[i]);
        }
//        ...
        adapter = new GridAdapter(MainActivity.this, NewWeb, NewImages);
//        ...
    }
```

**Adapter modification:**

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mcontext;

    ArrayList<Integer> images;
    ArrayList<String> web;

    public GridAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> web, ArrayList<Integer> images) {
        mcontext = c;
        this.images = images;
        this.web = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View grid;
        LayoutInflater layoutinflatr = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mcontext);
            grid = layoutinflatr.inflate(R.layout.gridxml, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            tv.setText(web.get(position));
            iv.setImageResource(images.get(position));
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        grid.setTag(position);
        grid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // code to delete the selected item.
                web.remove((int) v.getTag());
                images.remove((int) v.getTag());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I  tried your code. But while changing to array list app got crashed.I couldn't run the application